# Missing URL on some sites using BeautifulSoup and Requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape webpage to get articles but the links don't have http:, so I am getting request.expections.MissingSchema: Invalid URL error.

I know that I have to try something like 'http:'+ href, but where should I put this I can't understand.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time

url = "https://www.lanacion.com.ar/"

# Request
r1 = requests.get(url)
r1.status_code

# We'll save in coverpage the cover page content
coverpage = r1.content

# Soup creation
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(coverpage, 'html5lib')

# News identification
coverpage_news = soup1.find_all('h2', class_='com-title')
len(coverpage_news)

coverpage_news[2]

number_of_articles = 2

# Empty lists for content, links and titles
news_contents = []
list_links = []
list_titles = []

for n in np.arange(0, number_of_articles):
    
    # only news articles (there are also albums and other things)
    #if "inenglish" not in coverpage_news[n].find('a')['href']:  
    #    continue
    
    # Getting the link of the article
    link = coverpage_news[n].find('a')["href"] 
    list_links.append(link)
    
    # Getting the title
    title = coverpage_news[n].find('a').get_text()
    list_titles.append(title)
    
    # Reading the content (it is divided in paragraphs)
    article = requests.get(link)
    article_content = article.content
    soup_article = BeautifulSoup(article_content, 'html5lib')
    body = soup_article.find_all('h2', class_='title')
    x = body[0].find_all('p')
    
    # Unifying the paragraphs
    list_paragraphs = []
    for p in np.arange(0, len(x)):
        paragraph = x[p].get_text()
        list_paragraphs.append(paragraph)
        final_article = " ".join(list_paragraphs)
        
    news_contents.append(final_article)
```

Thanks so much!!

Comment: Try here: list_links.append("https:" + link)

Comment: I try but I haven't success.

Answer (score 0):

Add Prefix to link

```
# Getting the link of the article
link = coverpage_news[n].find('a')["href"] 
link = 'https://www.lanacion.com.ar'+link
list_links.append(link)
```

Comment: Well, I put this into the code but i now have an out of index error.                                                                  `IndexError: list index out of range`